# PHP imap_msgno returns zero once message moved from inbox, no way to move messages a second time

Tags: php, imap

In order to move a message using PHP's `imap_mail_move()` function you need the not-an-id fluff "id" that can be determined by using PHP's `imap_msgno()` function.

I have found across all the mail providers that once any given message is moved out of the inbox that `imap_msgno()` will always return 0. The [documentation page](https://www.php.net/imap_msgno) is bare bones is of absolutely no help.

I've filed a [PHP bug](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/7719) though I'm hoping someone has some sort of insight. I've tested the latest versions of PHP 7.3, 8.0 and 8.1 as of December 5th, 2021.

How do I force PHP's `imap_msgno()` to return the message id instead of zero once a message has been moved from the inbox?

- I have tested AOL, Gmail and Yahoo all with the same results across all the versions of PHP I've tested.
- I have been able to move the messages from the inbox to other folders via PHP's `imap_mail_move()` function.
- Yes, I'm using PHP's `imap_expunge()` function to commit the changes.
- Yes, I'm obviously passing the actual correct unique id.
- Yes, I've *verified* that the messages were moved by inspecting the folders *directly* at the mentioned mail providers.
- Yes, for the sake of trying everything I can think of I've attempted to move the messages using the unique id (in spite of the documentation for `imap_mail_move()` stating it requires the fluff "id") and obviously the attempt failed.

The errors for `imap_mail_move()` are obviously caused by not having the valid fluff "id" generated by `imap_msgno()`; I'm posting them here in case others are encountering this issue and haven't realized the root cause.

> Unknown: IMAP protocol error: [CLIENTBUG] COPY Command arguments invalid (errflg=2)

> Unknown: [CLIENTBUG] COPY Command arguments invalid (errflg=2)

Comment: After you moved it, did you check in the new mailbox (folder) (where you moved the message to) or did you check the same as you moved it from? If you checked the same as you moved it from, it make sense that it returns 0 since you just moved it out.

Comment: @M.Eriksson A comment mentioned that the `imap_mail_move()` doesn't actually move a message though instead makes a copy in the destination folder and then deletes the original. I've been working to verify that is the case, thank you for commenting.

Comment: Your premise is also wrong, you don't need to use imap_msgno.  You should provide UIDs and provide the CP_UID flag to imap_message_move.

Comment: And once you use imap_expunge, the message is gone.  That is the point of imap_expunge.